# Why when I insert a marker on a google maps fragment it didn't show?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I put a valid API and my map is working.

In my app I am trying to insert a marker on a google map, but when I insert it, it doesn't show in my app. You can see my problem below in the first image. I put the code in another project and it works. You can see in the second image.

In ***AndroidManifest.xml*** I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.recyclefinder">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RecycleFinder">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.RecycleFinder.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/second_fragment_label">
          
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

In ***MapsActivity.java*** I  have this:

```
package com.example.recyclefinder;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_second);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.8473567, 150.6517866);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(sydney)
                .title("Sydney"));
    }
}
```

I put the code in another project and it work. I think is not working because is a google map fragment and not a google map activity(I'm not sure because I am a beginner). I put the marker in Sydney because I want to test the marker.

[The project where I have the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajiZm.png)

[This is my second project, this is where I test new features before I add in the main project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV49z.png)

Comment: Hi! Your question isn't clear, I don't understand what is the issue you are facing. Please edit your question and add more information regarding which is the problem.

Comment: @Daniel I edited the question. 
I insert 2 images to see my problem. 
At the top I tried to describe better my problem.